# Проблемы при работе с vsimporter tool

Tags: xcode, uwp, windows-10, visual-studio-2015

Доброго времени суток! Мне стал интересен инструмент от Microsoft     vsimporter. Возникла такая проблема: при попытке конвертировать .xcodeproj проект в .sln проект в командной строке появляется сообщение "The "project" workspace does not contain any schemes". Все schemes на месте. Такая проблема возникает рандомно, т.к. удалось два проекта конвертировать, но с другими двумя проблема выше. Не могу понять из-за чего так. Если кто сталкивался с идентичной проблемой, буду рад любой подсказке!

Comment: может ему надо чтоб schemes были shared

Comment: schemes установлены shared. Это не решает проблему

Comment: убедитесь, что у схем контейнером указан воркспейс а не проект. может в именах схем какие то спецсимволы

Comment: я для этого проекта не создавал workspace. в контейнере только проект

Comment: в ошибке написано про workspace, странно

Comment: что и удивило меня